# cx_Oracle: Error 933. ORA-00933: “SQL command not properly ended”: SQL command error?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

Similar questions have been asked before but I've still been unable to identify a solution for this. My code:

```
    try:
        connection = cx_Oracle.connect(ORACLE_CONNECT)
        logger.info("Connection to Oracle success.")
        print ("Oracle DB version: " + connection.version)
        print ("Oracle client encoding: " + connection.encoding)
        print ("Python version: " + platform.python_version())
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        error, = e.args
        if error.code == 1017:
            print ("Username/password invalid.")
            logger.debug("Username/password invalid: %s", error.code)
        else:
            logger.debug("Database connection error: %s", e)
            print ("Database connection error: %s".format(e))
        raise

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    smsreport_text_new = tuple(smsreport_text)
    find_command = self.identify_unique_msgid(smsreport_list)
    cursor.execute(find_command)

 def identify_unique_msgid(self, smsreport_list):
    msgid_i_to_be_crosschecked = smsreport_list.get('msgid_i')
    msgid_ii_to_be_crosschecked = smsreport_list.get('msgid_ii')
    find_command = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE msgid_i = {0}'.format(msgid_i_to_be_crosschecked)
    print (find_command)

    return find_command
```

The `find_command` looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE msgid_i = 2R67C865FB6ZHG5A9
```

I've tried with and without a semi-colon at the end of the SQL query, but still fails. I know the connection works because I have another query (see below) and this writes data to the table. It's just when tried to find rows which contain certain values do I get this error message.

```
insert into xura_push (date_sms, result_sms, msgid, msgparts, msgid_i, msgid_ii) values (TO_DATE(:1, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Cheers, pymat.

Comment: Use parameters instead of putting values directly in strings.  More practically, you need single quotes around string constants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you mean the find_command should resemble the insert command above?

Comment: you can use this I guess `"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE msgid_i = \'{0}\'"` if you don't care much, but yes, you should use parameterized query.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal that seemed to work. If I'm making an query, how can I see the results of the query? The command just gets executed, but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @pymat you can use `db_records = cursor.fetchall();` and then iterate over `db_records`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, use parameters as in the following:

```
def identify_unique_msgid(self, smsreport_list):
    msgid_i_to_be_crosschecked = smsreport_list.get('msgid_i')
    msgid_ii_to_be_crosschecked = smsreport_list.get('msgid_ii')
    find_command = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE msgid_i = :msgid'
    return find_command, dict(msgid = msgid_i_to_be_crosschecked)

cursor = connection.cursor()
smsreport_text_new = tuple(smsreport_text)
find_command, args = self.identify_unique_msgid(smsreport_list)
cursor.execute(find_command, args)
```